# Bokeh - Update func for Slider

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I have some problem with updating the plot values with Bokeh. Select and Slider don't change the plot.  The code is supposed to plot 'budget' along with 'vote_average' in different years. Slider is for showing data (release_date) from 1970 to 2016 years. I'm working in the Jupyter notebook. Code is below:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data = {
   'x': movies.budget,
   'y': movies.vote_average,
   'revenue': movies.revenue,
   'profit': movies.profit,
   'original_title': movies.original_title,
   'release_date': movies.release_date
 })

p = figure(x_axis_label='Budget in millions $', y_axis_label='Rank',
      tools = [HoverTool(tooltips = '@original_title')])

p.circle(x = 'x', y = 'y', source=source)


def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    yr = slider.value
    # Set new_data
    new_data = {
        'x'       : data.budget.loc[data.release_date == str(yr)].values,
        'y'       : data.vote_average.loc[data.release_date == str(yr).values
}
    # Assign new_data to source.data
    source.data = new_data

slider = Slider(start=1970, end=2016, step=1, value=1970, title='Year')
slider.on_change('value', update_plot)

layout = row(widgetbox(slider), p)

show(layout)
```

What's supposed to be in 'update plot' function? It seems that this func just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Binding widgets in Jupyter notebook requires custom Javascript callbacks as far as I know. Your example would only work on a bokeh serve app. Check out [this notebook](https://hub.mybinder.org/user/bokeh-bokeh-notebooks-bmqi9uxx/notebooks/tutorial/06%20-%20Linking%20and%20Interactions.ipynb) to see how.